# Can't load calendar event with getEventByID for events created on iOS due to different eventId format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a Google Sheet with a list of events and each line contains the CalendarId and EventId.

Some EventId's are in a different format. For example:

```
- usual format: 2nn755esk1ddgg8bf4efabq5i0@google.com
- different format: 4F29BF66-4264-44E9-9162-9E6B9B97AF53
```

When I try to load an event with the different format I get "null" instead of the event object.

sample code:

```
// event load returns null
var calendar1 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('stepvda.net_qfrvg5ejjrv97ps04o16fjiokk@group.calendar.google.com');
var event1 = calendar1.getEventById('4F29BF66-4264-44E9-9162-9E6B9B97AF53'); 

// event code returns event object correctly
var calendar2 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('stepvda.net_dunvv2cuqlirkucfamgj0vec18@group.calendar.google.com');
var event2 = calendar2.getEventById('2nn755esk1ddgg8bf4efabq5i0@google.com');
```

I noticed that the different eventId format seems to come from events I created in iOS on my iPhone where the normal format are events I created in the Google Calendar web app.

Any idea how I can load events with the different format for the eventId?

Comment: Do you get the same problem when using the `Calendar` advanced service? Where did you get the `eventId`s from?

Comment: I have a separate function that downloads calendar event data into a Google Sheet. In this function I'm retrieving the eventId simply with the getId() method on the event object. In this function I'm able to retrieve all the events within a data range with: 
    events = calendar.getEvents(startDate, endDate);

I haven't used Calendar Advanced Service. As I understand this is a REST API and I haven't figured out yet how to use it from Google Apps Scipt. Do you some sample code by any chance?

Comment: I tried the following but I get a Not Found error back: 
 var event3 =  Calendar.Events.get('stepvda.net_qfrvg5ehirr97ps04o16fjiokk@group.calendar.google.com', '4F29BF57-4264-44E9-9162-9E449B97AF53');

Comment: I did some further debugging with the Advanced Calendar API. Here I found that the regular Calendar API is actually always returning the iCalUID of the event. However this iCalUID cannot always be used to retrieve an event with the regular Calendar API (cfr. case where event was created on iPhone). You have to use the normal Id which you apparently can only retrieve with the Advanced Calendar API.
I will log this as a bug with Google Issue tracker. It looks like this also means I found a workaround which means I need to completely migrate my code to the Advanced Calendar API.

Comment: Here's the link of the issue on the Google Issue tracker: [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110978459)

Comment: once you have the event's actual ID you can probably still use the simplified `CalendarApp` for a number of tasks. Good job debugging this

Comment: indeed, the Id retrieved with the Advanced API works with getEventById().